# How to hide items in the filtered sheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have two sheets on a dashboard, sheet 1 and sheet 2. both sheets are exactly the same with one column of values in each sheet. the only difference is Sheet 1 is used to filter Sheet 2. How can I hide the values in Sheet 2 if not row was select in sheet 1.

Example:
Here are the sheets next to each other
[image]

If I click on an item in sheet 1 it filters sheet 2 as expected
[image]

What I want to do is to hide the items in sheet 2 if no items are selected from Sheet 1. So it would look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the filter action to do nothing when no row is selected.

I've used Sheet 25 and 26 in the example below;

On Sheet 25; go to Worksheet - Actions - Add Action  - Filter

Configure your Filter Action as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is what I asked for. Thanks!